# How to merge imported config with environment config using Symfony Config as standalone component?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm integrating `symfony/config` (v3.3) into a legacy project as a standalone component.

Everything's going well except that the config processor does not merge  inherited/imported configuration `config.yml` with environment configuration `config_<ENV>.yml` (as I was expecting).

Instead of getting a merged configuration when calling `$container->getExtensionConfig('whatever_node')`, the resulted array contains both configs.

**EDIT 1**

It turns out that importing `parameters.yml` to replace config parameters does not work as well (i.e. using `%parameter_key%` into config files).

**EDIT 2**

Here's a full example of configuration regarding the `dev` environment:

```yaml
# parameters.yml
parameters:
    app_some_parameter_1: 'Some value for parameter 1'
    app_some_parameter_2: 'Another value for that second parameter'
```

```yaml
# config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }

app:
    some_parameter_1: '%app_some_parameter_1%'
    some_parameter_2: '%app_some_parameter_2%'
```

```yaml
# config_dev.yml
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

app:
    some_parameter_2: 'Parameter 2 value in the dev environment'
```

The expected config in the end:

```
[
    "some_parameter_1" => "Some value for parameter 1",
    "some_parameter_2" => "Parameter 2 value in the dev environment"
]
```

What I'm getting:

```
[
  [
    "some_parameter_1" => "%app_some_parameter_1%",
    "some_parameter_2" => "%app_some_parameter_2%"
  ],
  [
    "some_parameter_2" => "Parameter 2 value in the dev environment"
  ]
]
```

Comment: you try using %kernel.environment% ? maybe someting like this: config_ %kernel.environment%.yml ?

Comment: Not the problem here.

Comment: What do you mean by "both configs"? Could you share an exemple of config files, the configuration you got and the one you expected?

Comment: There it is @MatTheCat (see EDIT 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the array `ExtensionConfig` retrieved from the container (NB: I'm talking here of an "emulated" container not the one built by a common Symfony application) is not yet processed.

To get the resulting merged config, you need to process it using your own extension and configuration:

```php
# Acme/DependencyInjection/AcmeExtension.php
namespace Acme\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

class AcmeExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * @param array $configs
     * @param \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder $container
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $resolvedConfigs = [];

        foreach ($configs as $config) {
            $resolvedConfigs[] = $container->getParameterBag()->resolveValue($config);
        }

        return $this->processConfiguration(new Configuration(), $resolvedConfigs);
    }
}
```

```php
# Acme/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php
namespace Acme\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('acme');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                # ...
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```